# Create a class and decorate it at run time

Tags: c#, .net, class

I have a c# class like this

```
public class Info
{
public string PropertyName;
public int PropertyLength;

}
```

When i read a file and fetch data back to the class, it will look like

```
List<Info> information=new List<Info>();
```

//Code to read data from file and add it back to list

```
information - is a List collecting multiple entries...

0,1 - elements inside the list..

[0]
PropertyName - FirstName
PropertyLength - 25

[1]
PropertyName - LastName
PropertyLength - 50
```

I would like to generate a class at run time based on the above results

```
public class GeneratedClass
{

  [FieldLength(25)];
  public string FirstName;
  [FieldLength(50)];
  public string LastName;

}
```

How do i decorate it with say for example - FieldLength(the value for this one is coming from another source) at run time to get the desired result as above?

Answer (score 4):

[`Reflection.Emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ffc3x75(v=vs.110).aspx) contains many facilities to help you achieve this:

> Reflection emit provides the following capabilities:
>
> ...
>
> Define types in modules at run time, create instances of these types, and invoke their methods.

Separately (and despite never using it), it's my understanding that [you can also use a `TypeDescriptor` to achieve this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/parthopdas/archive/2006/01/03/509103.aspx):

> TypeDescriptor is an extensible inspection mechanism not just for components but for all Types and for individual instances of any given Type ... TypeDescriptor lets you inspect as well as modify the metadata (add, change and delete) of the target in any conceivable manner. The term target, for the rest of this text will refer to an element of the set of all .NET Framework Types (including Types imported from COM) and all instances of every .NET Framework Type.